# Путь к файлам в intellij Idea

Tags: java, изображения, intellij-idea, path

Я указываю тследующий относительный путь в параметрах, но это не работает.

```
   public static ArrayList<Integer> getNumbers() throws FileNotFoundException {
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("./src/main/resources/input.txt"));
    ArrayList<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
        list.add(scanner.nextInt());
    }
    return list;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Два важных вопроса. Относительно чего вы указываете относительный путь и почему? Почему вам не похдодит абсолютный путь?

Comment: мне нужно будет скинуть проект на проверку, и при абсолютном пути считывание из файла будет выдавать ошибку в другой системе

Comment: Это понятный ответ только на один из вопросов.

Comment: при указании абсолютного пути, это не будет срабатывать верно на другой системе, именно поэтому мне и нужен относительный

Comment: относительно названия проекта

Comment: "./src/main/resources/input.txt"

Comment: Относительный путь всегда относителен относительно текущей папки. До папки проекта ему нет никакого дела.

Comment: точку убери, чтобы было "/src/main/resources/input.txt"

Comment: так тоже не находит файл

Comment: ну значит его нету или неправильно введён путь. я ответ дополнил, попробуй.

Answer (score 0):

нажми правой кнопкой мыши на нужной папке в структуре проекта
и выбери пункт Copy Path...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и в появившемся меню выбери нужное...
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

если надо на диске узнать путь к файлу.
находим файл и жмём правой кнопкой мыши на нужном файле, в меню выбираем свойство
во вкладке безопасность копируем путь.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 //в корне
        File file = new File("input.txt");
        //в нужной папке
        File file2 = new File("/src/main/resources/input.txt");

        System.out.println(file.exists()); // файл существует?
        System.out.println(file2.exists()); // файл существует?

        System.out.println(file.createNewFile()); // файл создался?
        System.out.println(file2.createNewFile()); // файл создался?
```

Comment: Да, но это абсолютный путь, а мне нужен относительный

Comment: @mak 3й пункт - path from content root

Comment: он указан как src/main/resources/input.txt
Но такие варианты, как  1) new File("./src/main/resources/input.txt")
2)new File("../src/main/resources/input.txt") 3) new File("/src/main/resources/input.txt") не прошли

Comment: что значит не прошли?

Comment: система пишет, что указанный файл не найден

Comment: добавь в вопрос код

Comment: отредактировано

Comment: ну что пишет, создались файлы?

Comment: возвращает true, false, false, false
Если я указываю путь просто input.txt, то ошибки, что такого файла нет не выбрасывается, то и данные с него не считывается. Как будто файл пустой, либо оно создает новый пустой файл

Answer (score 0):

Корневым путем в вашем случае является `D:/Task1`, добавляя `../` вы отправляете сканер искать в родительской директории, т.е. в `D:` - естественно, путь некорректный. Для смещения относительно корневого каталога вниз используйте одну точку `./`, тогда поиск будет выполнен из `D:/Task1`:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File("./src/main/resources/input.txt"));
```

Comment: когда я указываю такой путь, система все равно не может найти файл